# How to connect the database tables and columns together using SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm working on an Android application. It involves SQLite Database. I've created 5 tables in one database and created 5 DBAdapters.

I have Primary keys in those tables (buddiesList,titles, event, likes & dislikes) and Foreign keys in 4 tables(titles, event, likes & dislikes). The tables are created in the SQLite Database.

Oh, one DBAdapter is where I coded to create the 5 tables and need to link the tables together and, primary & foreign keys together. While other 4 DBAdapters are for each of the 5 tables. I just post the codes and you may get what I'm saying and what I need.

AnniversaryDBAdapter - created 5 tables.

```
public class AnniversaryDBAdapter
{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Tables";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TITLE = "create table titles(title_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, image text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "create table buddiesList(name_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIKES = "create table likes(likes_id integer primary key autoincrement,like text not null, name_id integer not null, FOREIGN KEY(name_id) REFERENCES buddiesList(name_id));";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES = "create table dislikes(dlike_id integer primary key autoincrement, dislike text not null, name_id integer not null, FOREIGN KEY(name_id) REFERENCES buddiesList(name_id));";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS = "create table event(event_id integer primary key autoincrement, title_id integer not null, location text not null, starttime text not null, endtime text not null, desc text not null, date text not null, name_id integer not null, FOREIGN KEY(title_id) REFERENCES titles(title_id));";

    private final Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/main.page/Tables/";


    public AnniversaryDBAdapter(Context aContext)
    {
        this.context = aContext;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }




private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        /*try
        {
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LIKES);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TITLE);
            database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES);
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LIKES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TITLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES);
/*      database.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_budevent_nameid" +
                "BEFORE INSERT" +
                "ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" +
                "SELECT CASE WHEN((SELECT name_id FROM buddiesList WHERE name_id = new.name_id) IS NULL)" +
                "THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Foreign Key Violation')END;" +
                "END;");
        */


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");

        onCreate(db);

    }

}


public AnniversaryDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
/*  if(!db.isReadOnly())
    {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }*/
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
/*
public long insertEvent(String title,String location,String starttime,String endtime,String desc,String date, String name)
{
   ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();



   cValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
   cValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
   cValues.put(KEY_START, starttime);
   cValues.put(KEY_END, endtime);
   cValues.put(KEY_DESC, desc);
   cValues.put(KEY_ALARM, alarm);
   cValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
   cValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);


   return db.insert(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, null, cValues);

}

public boolean deleteEvent(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor getAllEvents()
{
    return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

}

public Cursor getEvent(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor c = db.query(true,CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_START, KEY_END, KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_NAME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
*/
}
```

As you can see in AnniversaryDBAdapter, in the buddiesList table, the name_id is the primary key which links to event, likes and dislikes table. The name_id in the event, likes and dislikes table is foreign key which is retrieved from the buddiesList table. But, when I key in the events details in Events page and save them into the event table, the name_id in the table should be a number which is retrieved from buddiesList table but instead it is stored as a name not an id. Same goes for the likes and dislikes.

Plus, if uncomment the `if(!db.isReadOnly())
    {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }`
I can't open information, events & SMS pages, I got force close message.

BuddyDBAdapter - buddiesList table

```
public class BuddyDBAdapter extends AnniversaryDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "name_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "buddiesList";

    //private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public BuddyDBAdapter(Context aContext)
    {
        super(aContext);
    }

    public long insertNames(String name)
    {
        ContentValues buddyValues = new ContentValues();
        buddyValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        return db.insert(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, null, buddyValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNames(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllNames()
    {

           return db.query(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);


    }

    public Cursor getNames(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(true, CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The codes in BuddyDBAdapter are similar to CalendarAdapter(event table), LikesDBAdapter(likes table) & DislikesDBAdapter(dislikes table) except for the table's and columns' names

My problem is, I'm not sure how to connect the tables together. And, how to enable foreign keys in SQLite Database.

Even if I type like

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TITLE = "create table titles(title_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, image text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BUDDIESLIST = "create table buddiesList(name_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LIKES = "create table likes(likes_id integer primary key autoincrement,like text not null, name_id integer not null, FOREIGN KEY(name_id) REFERENCES buddiesList(name_id));";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DISLIKES = "create table dislikes(dlike_id integer primary key autoincrement, dislike text not null, name_id integer not null FOREIGN KEY(name_id) REFERENCES buddiesList(name_id));";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS = "create table event(event_id integer primary key autoincrement, title_id integer not null, location text not null, starttime text not null, endtime text not null, desc text not null, date text not null, name_id integer not null, FOREIGN KEY(name_id) REFERENCES buddiesList(name_id), FOREIGN KEY(title_id) REFERENCES titles(title_id));";
```

and

```
if(!db.isReadOnly())
    {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }
```

I still have the force close error.

Plus,I'm not sure how to connect the name_id from buddiesList table to the event, likes & dislikes tables. Same goes for, connect the title_id from titles table to the title_id in event table.

Can anyone help me out on this? Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd show the `logcat` output for the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking some indexes; see [Required and Suggested Database Indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).

When changing data, ensure that it is valid at all times, e.g., insert a parent before its child, and delete all children before their parent.